# Como pegar conteúdo de array javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa tarde galera do Stack Overflow.

Estou sentindo enorme dificuldade de pegar conteúdo de um array em especifico em javascript.

Nas primeiras linhas de código de javascript fica assim.
Solto

```
var arrayIDs = [];
```

Depois de um tempo, ele executa o seguinte código

```
$(".form-group").find('*').each(function() {

    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    if ($("#" + id).val() > 0) {
        if ($("#" + id).data("id-produto-item") != undefined) {
     arrayIDs.push({
         id_produto_itens: $("#" + id).data("id-produto-item"),
         id_proposta: numeroProposta
     });
   }
}
});
```

Depois que os dados são preenchidos, eu no final preciso manipula-los.

Quando eu dou um console.log no arrayIDs, aparece isso aqui pra mim:

```
*→ []
→ 0: {id_produto_itens: 150, id_proposta: "123"}
→ 1 : {id_produto_itens: 160, id_proposta: "123"}
→ 2: {id_produto_itens: 176, id_proposta: "123"}
→ 3: {id_produto_itens: 175, id_proposta: "123"}
length: 4__proto__: Array(0)*
```

O problema ocorre quando eu quero percorrer os valores da seguinte forma, sendo que assim ele nem entra dentro do $.each

Não apresenta mensagem de erro nem nada, ai quando eu coloco um console.log("mensagem") nem entra nessa "mensagem"

```
$(document).on('click','#btnSalvar',function () {
   $.each(arrayIDs, function (key, value) {
      console.log("mensagem")
      console.log(arrayIDs.id_produto_itens);
   });
});
```

A pergunta é, como pegar o conteúdo esse array?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Edit 1:** Vou colocar exatamente quando cada trecho é chamado

Comment: Olá gabriel, alguma resposta solucionou o teu problema?

Answer (score 1):

Seu array não é um objeto `JQuery`, por isso não funciona no [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

Converta-o para um objeto `JQuery` e o mesmo funcionará:

```js
let arrayIDs = [];

arrayIDs.push({
  "id_produto_itens": 1
},
{
  "id_produto_itens": 2
});

$(arrayIDs).each(function (key, value) {
    console.log(arrayIDs[key].id_produto_itens);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: tentei colocar de uma forma um pouco mais explicativa

Ambas não funcionam

Answer (score 1):

Você pode pegar o elemento que está sendo iterado no each utilizando o this.

```js
var arrayIDs = [
  {id_produto_itens: 150, id_proposta: "123"},
  {id_produto_itens: 160, id_proposta: "123"},
  {id_produto_itens: 176, id_proposta: "123"},
  {id_produto_itens: 175, id_proposta: "123"}
];

 $.each(arrayIDs, function () {
    console.log("id_produto_itens: " + this.id_produto_itens + ", id_proposta: " + this.id_proposta);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra alternativa somente com `JS` sem ter de converter seu `array` para um `objeto JQuery` é utilizando o método [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) que executa uma dada função em cada elemento de um `array`, assim você precisará criar uma função para acessar os elementos do seu array.

Abaixo, criei uma função que exibe o valor `id_produto_itens` do array e coloquei essa função como parâmetro do `forEach()`.

```js
var arrayIDs = [];

arrayIDs.push({id_produto_itens: 150, id_proposta: "123"});
arrayIDs.push({id_produto_itens: 160, id_proposta: "123"});
arrayIDs.push({id_produto_itens: 176, id_proposta: "123"});
arrayIDs.push({id_produto_itens: 175, id_proposta: "123"});

arrayIDs.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(item.id_produto_itens);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seu código está corretíssimo, **EXCETO** que esqueceu de colocar o índice `[key]` ao chamar o item da array:

```
                  faltou isso
                      ↓
console.log(arrayIDs[key].id_produto_itens);
```

**Porém**, eu sugeriria que você usasse o parâmetro `value` que representa cada item da array:

```
$.each(arrayIDs, function (key, value) {
   console.log("mensagem")
    console.log(value.id_produto_itens);
});
```

**Veja funcionando:**

```js
var arrayIDs = [];

arrayIDs.push(
{
     id_produto_itens: 1,
     id_proposta: 123
},
{
     id_produto_itens: 2,
     id_proposta: 123
}
);

$.each(arrayIDs, function (key, value) {
   console.log("mensagem")
    console.log(value.id_produto_itens);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```